# How can I add a class to my own console app project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

I am facing this problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V5Zy.png)when trying to add a new class to my project
Can anyone help me please

Comment: What steps are you doing to add new class?

Comment: from Project <Add class>

Comment: Maybe resetting your development environment works? See this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003924

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: @محمدفردوسي, if you have problem in adding a new class to your project, I suggest that you can define a class in your program.cs file directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot add class to your project using IDE, as a workaround you can do it manually.

1. Go to your project's directory (where `Program.cs` is located)
2. Create new file named `Class1.cs` (you can give any name)
3. Go to Visual Studio and see is new class appeared.
4. If it didn't click on `Show All Files`, see your class, right click on it and choose `Include in project`

[image]

But this is obviously not a long term solution. Try repairing your `Visual Studio` using `Visual Studio Installer`

Comment: i facing sim issues when adding  new file

Comment: Is issue occurring on step 4?

Comment: Add fine without using Visual Studio (for example using Windows File Explorer)